# Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

Tags: core-data, swift2

xcode started complaining about the following code (worked fine w/o any issues for quite a few months):

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)

        request.returnsDistinctResults = true

        let nsArr: NSArray = ["int_field", "date_field"]

        request.propertiesToFetch = nsArr as [AnyObject]

        request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(val1 == %d) AND (val2 == %@)", argumentArray: [anIntegerValue, aStringValue])

        request.predicate = predicate

        do {

            let results: NSArray = try moc.executeFetchRequest(request)

            for result in results {
```

Up to this point all is fine. But when I try to extract data from a result, I get an 'Ambiguous use of 'subscript' error on the following:

```
let val1 = result["int_field"] as! Int 
let val2 = result["date_field"] as! NSDate
```

Not sure what is happening, but if I replace the above syntax with:

```
let val1 = (result as! NSDictionary) ["int_field"] as! Int
let val2 = (result as! NSDictionary)["date_field"] as! NSDate
```

it works. What I am not clear about is why declaring the following is not sufficient (or what happened in ios 9.2 to cause this):

```
request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a close look, the proposed solution by Vadian did not work for me.

The only thing that worked was my original solution:

```
let val1 = (result as! NSDictionary) ["int_field"] as! Int
let val2 = (result as! NSDictionary)["date_field"] as! NSDate
```

It seems that the trigger was importing Realm framework (to address another dependency). All I can say is that when I removed Realm, the error/issue goes away.

This occurs despite me not actually using Realm at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

**Please use Swift native collection types, they are so much easier to maintain.**

First of all, assign the array directly to `propertiesToFetch`. No `NSArray`, no `[AnyObject]`

```
request.propertiesToFetch = ["int_field", "date_field"]
```

Your result is an array of dictionaries which have `String` keys and `Int` / `NSDate` values. Multiple types must be represented by `AnyObject`.

```
do {
   let results = try moc.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Now, since the compiler knows that the array contains dictionaries this will smoothly compile

```
   for result in results {
     let val1 = result["int_field"] as! Int 
     let val2 = result["date_field"] as! NSDate
   }
}
```

Foundation collection types don't contain the type information and can cause those `Ambiguous use` messages.

Comment: Interesting. While I 'get' why it makes sense to add the type to the result (and I take your point on the Swift native collections), I do not understand what suddenly caused xcode to complain now (code has been running happily for a few months). Thoughts?

Comment: There were a few changes in Swift 2.0 and 2.1. if a project has compiled successfully in an earlier version, the app runs fine. The issues occur always at compile time running a different Swift version.

Comment: That's what puzzles me. It just started complaining today. And it has been compiling and running fine throughout the day...never mind. Something has changed and the solutions (yours and mine) work. Thanks!